# When is the right time to disabled the button for submission?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript where finally I do a check of if and else as below. The problem when I added document.getElementById("Submit").disabled = true; the form is never submitted ? Any idea how to disabled it from user clicking twice?

```
if(gotError=="true")
            {

                return false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("Submit").disabled = true;
                return true;
            }
```

Here is my html of the button

```
<input class="buttons" type="Submit" id="Submit" name="<?php echo $submitTag?>" value="<?php echo $submitTag?>">
```

Comment: can you show your HTML?

Comment: Why do you want to disable it if there is no error?

Comment: @Ibu I have added the html of the button

Comment: the problem why I need to disabled I saw two subimssion of the same value which I think is due to twice clicking it

Comment: I don't even know why disabling `#Submit` would stop the form from submitting. Do you have a working demo?

Comment: yes the codes are long

Comment: Usually submitting a form twice doesn't result in sending the arguments twice as well. Instead, your server would receive two requests, but the first would never be accepted by your client anymore... thus there must be an error in your code elsewhere. But I'm just stating the general case...

Comment: No is the same arguement but repeated in two lines of the db. So what you think. Only happen once so far. IF the codes have issue then it should be always repeating rite

Comment: Are you doing any kind of ajax or such? Otherwise a form cannot be submitted twice due to page unloading.

Comment: No ajax during submission